# Access Azure App Service backend from Azure Function using MobileServiceClient

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c

Within my Xamarin.Forms App, I access my Azure App Service C# based backend by instantiating a MobileServiceClient so that I can easily work with Tables and creating a PublicClientApplication (MSAL) so that I can easily authenticate users against Azure Active Directory B2C. The latter results in a context that also contains an AccessToken which I can pass as a ZumoPayload to the login call of the MobileServiceClient (because after all, this one needs authentication as well).

On the other hand, I also have Azure Functions and I want them to also access the Azure App Service C# based backend. However, not as a user, but as a service instead.

So that I can authenticate the MobileServiceClient instance, it needs an Access Token as well. I thought about using the AzureServiceTokenProvider to retrieve one as it implements a GetAccessTokenAsync method.

However, it needs a ressource and I am not able to find out the proper procedure to get things working here in this constellation. I believe I need to register another B2C Application, set up some redirect URIs properly and configure permissions... but I can't get it right and tutorials I found up to now didn't help me. :(

I am open to suggestions. ;-)

Comment: Per my understanding, you have a Azure App Service C# based backend which is protected by Azure AD B2C, and now you want to access your backend app from Azure function, right?

Comment: That's correct. This is because I have Azure Functions that are executed based on a timer and some are running as webhooks triggered by external sources. Because of this, I need them to authenticate via MSI.

Comment: I see, you can use the client_id as the resource.

Comment: I tried different identifiers yet. Per your hint also the client_id of the App Service I want the Function to be able to call. The response is always "You don't have the permission to view this directory or page". I am receiving an access token however, but the LoginAsync call of MobileServiceClient returns the above error message:

client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, zumoPayload); 

With

var zumoPayload = new JObject()
{
  ["access_token"] = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync( client_id )
};

Comment: I believe the difference is, that when a mobile client authenticates against B2C, a user account is used. Hence, when using MSAL, I get an authenticationResult that contains a valid Access Token that can be passed to the MobileServiceClient instance for logging in to zumo. However, when an Azure Function tries to authenticates, I don't use MSAL. So at some place, there needs to be a Managed Identity in place with proper permissions and I am not able to find out how to do this...

Comment: Usually you’d use an AAD App registration in your B2C tenant when you need a service go service call authenticated with client credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the whole process of authentication is rigged to use Azure App Service Authentication & Authorization, which doesn't allow for a managed identity to work.  So, short version, you can't get there from where you are.

I do have some ideas on how to support this feature, but the current client is very restrictive and tightly coupled in terms of authentication.  Any change in this area would have to wait until the next major release.